# Symfony 3.3.3 Generating missing files via the command assets:install

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

Since the new version of symfony 3.3.3, the command : `php bin/console assets:install` do not create anymore file in the directory **web/bundles/**.

You have an idea to solve concerns ?
For the moment, I copy last there the contents of the missing files... :)

I'm use Windows OS

Comment: it may be permission problem, I m using symfony 3.3 and it still create the web/bundles directory with assets... maybe try a `-vvv` more verbose option

Comment: I also looked at, and the web folder at all recursive access.

Comment: I've been having the same problem on the new Symfony 2.8  on multiple projects.

All are missing assets

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23373

It has been reported on the Symfony repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is comming...

Reference : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/6298e69f29b7ef8bdde357a2ce87e8f4843d1fd8

### ---

**UPDATE**

New minor version available : http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-3-4-released